Is it possible to force narrowing of a string type to the actual string value used?
Given a "passthrough" function that forwards an object where one of the keys is a string, is it possible to infer the type of that string prop as the actual value used rather than have it typed as string?
E.g.,
function passthrough(arg: {name: string}) { return arg; };

// `res` should be inferred as `{name: "Foo"} | {name: "Bar"}`
const res = passthrough(Math.random() < 0.5 ? {name: "Foo"} : {name: "Bar"});


Do you require {name: "Foo"} | {name: "Bar"}, or are various other things like {name: "Foo" | "Bar"} or {readonly name: "Foo"} | {readonly name: "Bar"} acceptable? The former is what the below answer gives you; the latter would be done this way.

Thanks for the playground link @jcalz, very useful, was looking for a union of object types rather than the prop being a union of strings

So then do you want to see my suggestion as an answer?

Sure, I'll mark it as answer

In order for the function return type to depend on the input that way, the function must be generic. There are different generic call signatures that could keep track of the string literal type of the name property of arg, but if you want the function to return a union type when the input is a union, then my suggestion would be to write the function like this:
function passthrough<const T extends { name: string }>(arg: T) { return arg; };

Here arg is of the generic type T which is constrained to {name: string}. So if arg is of a union type then the return type will also be of a union type.
And note that I've made T a const type parameter so that arg will be inferred to keep track of literal types and not just string.
Let's test it:
const res = passthrough(Math.random() < 0.5 ? { name: "Foo" } : { name: "Bar" });
/* const res: {
    readonly name: "Foo";
} | {
    readonly name: "Bar";
} */

Looks good.

Note that the input is inferred as having readonly properties because that's what const type parameters do. This isn't exactly what you asked for, but {readonly name: "Foo"} | (readonly name: "Bar"} and {name: "Foo"} | (name: "Bar"} are mutually assignable, so hopefully that isn't a big deal either way.
If it is a big deal you could always explicitly use a mapping modifier to remove readonly from the properties:
function passthrough<const T extends { name: string }>(arg: T) {
    const ret: { -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K] } = arg;
    return ret;
};

const res = passthrough(Math.random() < 0.5 ? { name: "Foo" } : { name: "Bar" });
/* const res: {
    name: "Foo";
} | {
    name: "Bar";
} */

Playground link to code
